# Fatal SIGSEGV error in Java Runtime Environment

Tags: linux, java, jvm-hotspot, segmentation-fault

Following error is received while running a java application on linux, crashing the jvm:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x000000000000003a, pid=7629, tid=140107993413376
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000000000003a
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

For full error log see http://pastebin.com/NghPkCpx

Not sure where to begin with this, usually I would check Java frames :

```
Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec([B[BI[BI[BZLjava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;)I+0
j  java.lang.UNIXProcess.access$500(Ljava/lang/UNIXProcess;[B[BI[BI[BZLjava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;)I+18
j  java.lang.UNIXProcess$1$1.run()V+93
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

Although not sure what to make from this, any ideas how to go about debugging?

Answer (score 5):

Unless you have your own JNI code, you've hit a bug in Java itself, and there's no point to 'debugging' it. Best you can do is look for a newer release of the JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, could share/expand on your reasoning/conclusion? 
With previous segmentation faults, we have been able do debug java frames info, for instance http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9525779
Would it be worth moving this issue into oracle forums?

Comment: Let put it this way: should you, as a Java programmer, take care ("debug") about issues in JVM native code, platform native libraries, kernel code, hardware ROM code and processor wiring? If you believe you should, you may feel happier if moved away from Java to a more closer to hardware jobs.

Comment: Report it to Oracle, and try to find a workaround meanwhile. Wait for them to fix it. Sleep tight.

Comment: The oracle page you reference is talking about problems with *your* jni. Your backtrace is into *their* code.